# Action Bar ушел под TabHost

Tags: java, android

У меня 2 таба, то есть есть Main.Activity и еще 2 других. И Action уходит низ TabHost... Как сделать наоборот, чтобы табы были снизу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public class Tabs extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs_layout);

    // получаем TabHost
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // инициализация была выполнена в getTabHost
    // метод setup вызывать не нужно

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab 1");
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, FirstTab.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab 2");
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, SecondTab.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
}
```

**TabsLayout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

**FirstTab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FirstTab">

<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Text">
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SecondTab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/rightPadding"
android:background="#f2f2f2">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lvAll"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Разметку tab_layout приложите. Зачем здесь код, если у вас проблемы с размещением на разметке

Comment: Немного не в тему, но не могу не поразиться, с каким упорством андроид-разработчики до сих пор используют вьюхи, устаревшие 2-3 года назад. Используйте TabLayout, для вас же люди стараются. Ну и Toolbar, конечно. С этим вы получите намного более прозрачную разметку, в которой таким вот необъяснимым косякам места просто не останется.

Comment: Пока ты не сказал, я этого не знал, попробую теперь на нем... Тоже немножко не по теме, а с ним(TabLayout) как на  этом табхосте не будет проблем с ListView!? Теперь к вопросу... Может что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать AppBarLayout вместо стандартного ActionBar, при этом тема вашего Activity должна быть windowActionBar = false. Пример:
style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

manifests:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

xml Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```